# Где можно посмотреть проекты опытных разработчиков?

Tags: c#, unity3d, github

Я можно скачать новичок в unity, что то умею, а что то нет.

Я бы хотел посмотреть проекты профессиональных разработчиков. Я знаю что есть GitHub, но не знаю как найти именно то, что мне нужно.

Заранее спасибо)

Comment: в [этом топике](https://github.com/topics/unity) гитхаба есть много разных работ в юнити. Чем они вам не подходят?

Comment: [вот](https://github.com/UnityTechnologies/open-project-1), к примеру, создают игру сообществом, можно и посмотреть код и свой вклад внести

Comment: Читать чужие проекты, это тоже навык и ни на одном из них не висит бирки "он хорошо написан" или "он плохо написан", не занимайтесь фигней. Могу только сказать что Unity Lern это не про навыки программирования, это про инструменты фреймворка, код там в целом отвратный.